# Method string to byte

Tags: java, string, byte

I spend all the day trying to find the answer, so finally I write here.
I encrypt one string with class crypto and I get a byte[].
I have to convert this byte in string with tostring(), to upload in one web.
I need to get this string, decrypts and get the original string.
My problem is about getBytes, that not return the same byte[] to decrypt.

I need convert the original string to byte[], encrypt, get the byte[] that returns, convert to string and then, this string convert to byte[] and get the same byte[] encrypted.

I try all that it was in my mind.
I need some method that with one string, returns always the same byte[] and getbytes don't make this.

I add one example:

```
      String s2="this is an example";
      byte[] b1=s2.getBytes("UTF-8");
      byte[] b2=s2.getBytes("UTF-8");
      System.out.println("Byte s:"+b1);
      System.out.println("Byte s:"+b2);
```

There is one method that from one string give the same byte[]?
With getBytes (at least at me) I obtain two different byte[].
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very hard to follow, probably due to English not being your native language.  Can you post some code showing what you are doing and what you are getting out that is not what you want?

Comment: What charset are you using when decoding from byte[] to String and what charset are you using when encoding from String to byte[]? You must use the same charset for both or you may not get the original byte[].

Comment: It's not my native language, sorry.
I post an example about my problem.
If I write this:
          String s="this is an example";
          byte[] b1=s.getBytes("UTF-8");
          byte[] b2=s.getBytes("UTF-8");
          System.out.println("Byte s:"+b1);
          System.out.println("Byte s:"+b2);
I obtain two different byte. I need something that for one String I obtain one byte[], a symmetrical relation byte[]-->String-->byte[] with both byte equals.
I tried all the charset,default, UTF-8...and I was care about encode and decode with the same.
Thanks you both.

Comment: @Jmm: In your example, you are printing out the addresses of the two byte arrays which are different in this case. If you want to check for content equality, use `Arrays.equals(b1, b2)`. Is that returning true? It should for the same string and encoding.

Comment: Do you need more help to resolve this issue? Please ask for more information if needed.

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstand the following line

```
System.out.println("Byte s:"+b1);
```

Here we are implicitly calling the `toString()` method on the byte array. This does **not** return the contents of the array. Instead use:

```
System.out.println("Byte s:" + java.util.Arrays.toString(b1));
```

This will show you the contents of the byte array that you can use for your comparison.

Your use of the `String.getBytes(String)` method is fine. It is returning two different byte array *instances* but both have the same contents.

```
@Test
public void testGetBytes() throws Exception {
    String s2 = "this is an example";

    byte[] b1 = s2.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] b2 = s2.getBytes("UTF-8");

    Assert.assertEquals(b1, b2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`String#getBytes(charsetName)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29) which takes a specific character encoding.

```
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
// ...
```

Then, to reconstruct the string, you need to use the [`String(bytes, charsetName)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor which takes a specific character encoding.

```
String string = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
// ...
```

Otherwise the platform default character encoding will be used to decode the characters of the string to bytes. The platform default character encoding is not necessarily the same on all platforms. One platform may use UTF-8 while the other platform uses CP1252 or ISO-8859-1, for example.

Alternatively, you can use [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) to encode/decode the bytes into an US-ASCII compatible string so that it's compatible with practically every decent character encoding the world is aware of.

Comment: I tried this method getBytes and I have the problem I told.
I will try base64, thanks.

Comment: Then your problem is caused elsewhere and likely not solveable by Base64. It's impossible to pinpoint the cause of your problem without an SSCCE from your side. My best guess would be that the string is in turn written over network using the wrong encoding. Perhaps you were using some `Writer` without wrapping it in `OutputStreamWriter` or without just writing `string.getBytes("UTF-8")` to `OutputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

> I have to convert this byte in string with tostring(), to upload in one web

No, you don't. You can upload bytes just fine, and in fact bytes are the only thing you can send via HTTP. At some point your string will be converted back to bytes, so why not skip the extra conversions that only corrupt your data?

Comment: Because it's specified by the library I use upload with string.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to omit the conversion to String? I mean, you could send the byte[] and receive the byte[]. Or you could encode the byte[] using base64 (which produces a series of printable characters), send that as a String, and then decode it back from base 64 and obtain the original byte[].

Comment: Not it's possible to omit the conversion because I use a library to upload the information and it needs a string.
About encode the byte[] using base64 I didn't try, maybe it works.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried recreating the string and getting the bytes from it by specifying the encoding explicitly?

```
final String newString = new String(bytes, utf8_charset);
final byte[] bytes = oldString.getBytes(utf8_charset);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be occuring because JDK is unable to correctly recongnize the character set.
Use the declaration:

```
public byte[] getBytes(String charsetName)
```

to specify the character set to use. This may help. I see no other reason why it would return a different byte array.